# Is it possible to generate image using HTML5 canvas on a server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, v8

I'd like to ask if is possible to generate canvas image on a server side.
I wonder if someone has already experiences with it.

Why do I need something like that?
I'm planning to create client side canvas, which will contain some image + shapes (based on some data) and user must be able to e.g. draw new shapes, download all together as PNG, delete shapes... all this should be possible.

BUT, there should be also option to pick images from a list (imagine data grid view + checkboxes) on client side and download all selected images together as single ZIP file.

Requirement is, that images should be rendered the same way as on client side canvas (image + shapes). So I would like to take JavaScript code that generates canvas on client side and use it also on server side. Please note, that whole application will run on ASP.NET (IIS).

What came first on my mind as a first option is:

- request from client to server (list of IDs, + some properties like a ZIP file name)
- ASP.NET server perform a request(s) to NodeJS for images (+ parameters)
- NodeJS will generate canvas and return an image for each request
- ASP.NET server will pack all images returned from NodeJS and return them to a client

Question 1: Will this work?

Question 2: Can I somehow get rid of NodeJS? Current web application is build on ASP.NET MVC which runs on IIS and I don't want to mess server with another web server.

Question 3: Maybe I could be able to get rid of NodeJS by creating hidden canvas elements (will be rendered?) on a client, send their images from client to server by ajax and then let client download them as ZIP. (network bandwith is NOT a problem, it will be on a fast local network)

Thanks for sharing your experiences!

**UPDATE**

Another possibility I found is openning page in IE using powershell. Here's a working sample I have (but I'm not sure if this is the best solution).

```
 $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
 $ie.navigate("http://localhost:8080/img/id") # or whatever page that contains canvas
 $ie.visible=$false
 while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 500}
 $doc=$ie.document
 while(!$doc)
 {
    Write-Host -NoNewLine ".";
    Start-Sleep -m 50
    $doc=$ie.document
 }
 $canvas = $doc.getElementByID("canvasID")
 Start-Sleep -m 1000 # sometimes need additional time to render canvas background image
 $img = $canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1)
 $base64data = $img.Split("{,}")[1]
 $bytes  = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64data)
 [io.file]::WriteAllBytes('c:\temp\CanvasImage.png', $bytes)
```

Comment: You could drive PhantomJS or Selenium from the ASP.NET application I guess. They should allow saving the rendering result to a file. That said this seems like a roundabout way of doing it, basically you want to use Javascript as a way of defining an image? Why not just throw together a data format that you can process using whatever is appropriate on either side?

Comment: Or save the image as some vector format, like svg?

Comment: That said, your question isn't very clear to me, can you maybe outline a simplified example of what you're trying to accomplish? As in, what sort of data originates where and goes where and what happens to it to generate what. ("data grid view + checkboxes" could mean anything.)

Comment: PhantomJS (or Selenium) looks interesting. Maybe a good replacement of NodeJS.

Comment: @millimoose: that's what I want to do - use the same code for client and server side. There is already a Silverlight aplication with works really good (also supports image server generating side with some hacks), but SL is dead now. It won't be just a simple drawing. It will be a quite complicated and complex so datasource for generating image will be a big complex JSON object/structure. SVG or Canvas... I'd rather prefer canvas. Vector format is not a solution, I need a PNG.

Comment: Typically a server delivers assets (img's, etc) and the client-side lets the user assemble their desire result. Why are you reversing this design pattern -- it adds difficulty that might not be required? If you must reverse the process you have the choices (depending on IIS version) of GDI, GDI+, Direct2D and 3rd party libraries to compose drawings and export to bitmaps directly on the server.

Comment: Yes, typically... If I had to solve typical use case, propably I wouldn't ask on stackoverflow how to solve it.
I'd like to use single JS code to render images images with burned in shapes on both - client and server. Client will contain some additional features (like adding/moving shapes...), but both sides have to be able to download image as PNG/JPG. Server must be able to take a bunch of images, burn in shapes and pack them to ZIP file. They MUST be exatly the same what user can see when adding shapes on image (and use the same code for rendering).